# Can i sort structure in c++ using stl sort

Tags: sorting, stl, structure

I was trying to sort a structure using stl sort in C++ . But i get some error . Is it that we cannot sort a structure in c++ using stl sort or is it my fault in implementation , if its my fault do let me know the correction .

Here's the code (its very small :) )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct log {
       int sd;
       int ed;
} log[1000];
bool key(int i,int j) {
 return (log[i].ed<log[j].ed);
}
int main() {
int n,i;
cin>>n;
sort(log,log+n,key);
for (i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>log[i].sd>>log[i].ed;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<log.sd<<","<<log.ed<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But your comparator should take two `const log &` (not `int`) arguments.

Comment: Umm... well i am beginner in c++ , could tell me more where i should put 'const log &' ?

Comment: @ManasVerma `bool key(const log &a, const log &b) { return (a.ed < b.ed); }`

Comment: BTW. Most people prefer to use a functor (function object) rather than a regular function in such cases, though the latter also works.

Comment: i used did editing as you said but still it would give error - "8 expected `,' or `...' before '&' token " & also more error like 'a','b' not declared , "8`ISO C++ forbids declaration of `log' with no type " ,etc !!!

Comment: @ManasVerma Oh, you should rename either your structure or your array. Using the same name confuses the compiler.

Comment: okay i renamed my structure to logr , still it produces all same errors !

Comment: Then your arguments should also have type `const logr &`